# Will these two MS queries give me the same output?

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I'm updating some queries as an assignment for work. The bottom query is the updated version with different syntax, and the top is the old query. I just want to double check that the two queries will end with the same results:

```
SELECT a.breed
FROM dogs a, cats b, fish c
WHERE a.breed = b.breed AND a.tail = 0 AND b.size = c.size AND c.gills = 0 AND c.fin = @fin

----

SELECT a.breed 
FROM dogs a 
INNER JOIN cats b ON a.breed = b.breed
INNER JOIN fish c ON b.size = c.size
WHERE c.gills = 0 AND a.tail = 0 AND c.fin = @fin
```

Edit 1: fixed the format of the question to better represent what I meant. I changed the names of the tables and columns just in case.

Comment: Also [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).  There isn't a single letter `c` is the name `fish` so why alias it `c` and not `f`?

Comment: @Larnu I read it as OP is updating _to_ SQL-92 syntax.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I fixed the question to be less confusing and I changed the names of the columns/tables just in case

Comment: Probably answers your question in an *overkill* manner: [HoTTSQL: Proving Query Rewriteswith Univalent SQL Semantics \[PDF\]](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~suciu/hottsql.pdf)

Comment: You are doing the right thing to use the updated version, which is equivalent to the old one, but uses modern proper syntax.

Comment: The easiest way to therefore tell if they work to same would be to run them and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these queries will return the same results.